# Limiting combined count of 2 separate lists - C#

Tags: c#, list, count

I have the following class in a Visual C# project:

```
    public class Bus
    {
    private int BusNumber;
    public int busNumber
    {
        get { return BusNumber; }
        set { BusNumber = value; }
    }

    public List<CircularRoute> circularRoute = new List<CircularRoute>();
    public List<LongDistance> longDistance = new List<LongDistance>();
    }
```

Is there any way that I can limit the count of both lists combined? I know that I could do this easily using an if statement, if I used a polymorphic list. This isn't an option for me at the moment though.

Comment: do the lists join in anyway? do you want a 50, 50 split in the limit allowed?

Comment: Limit the count? How do you mean? Do you mean you want the total number of items of the combined list to never be more than a certain threshold?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I can limit the count of one list by using an if statement similar to: 'if (circularRoute.Count >= 5) { MessageBox.Show("blahblah"); }'... I guess that stops the user adding another object to the list. I need this message to show if the combined total of the two lists exceeds 10.

Comment: Does CircularRoute and LongDistanceRoute have a common bsae class/interface?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't limit length of list.

What you can - make public properties of type `IEnumerable<T>`. And methods, which add or remove items from private lists. Implement any logic on those methods.

```
public class Bus
{
    private int busNumber;
    private List<CircularRoute> circularRoutes = new List<CircularRoute>();
    private List<LongDistance> longDistances = new List<LongDistance>(); 
    private const int MaxTotalRoutes = 10;

    public int BusNumber
    {
        get { return busNumber; }
        set { busNumber = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CircularRoute> CircularRoutes
    {
        get { return circularRoutes; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<LongDistance> LongDistances
    {
        get { return longDistances; }
    }

    public void AddRoute(CircularRoute route)
    {
        if (circularRoutes.Count + longDistances.Count == MaxTotalRoutes)
        {
             // throw exception, do nothing, whatever 
             return;
        }

        circularRoutes.Add(route);
    }

    // add methods for adding and removing routes
}
```

**BTW** in C# we use PascalCase for names of properties, and camelCase for fields.

Comment: Using `IEnumerable<T>` as type for the properties does not ensure that objects can't be added. The runtime type will determine whether or not items can be added. Not the declared compile time type

Comment: @RuneFS is right. In calling code I could do `((List<CircularRoute>)aBus.CircularRoutes).Add(new CircularRoute())`. That's why returning a _copy_ of the list is better protection of the class invariants.

Comment: @Oded in calling code I can use reflection. So, what then? We are talking about correct usage of code

Comment: We are talking about protecting class invariants. A caller may very well decide to do this cast in order to add to the list _because they need to_.

Comment: @Oded how do you know that I'm using `List<T>` to store routes internally? Maybe I use `Dictionary<int,CircularRoute>` and just returning `ValuesCollection`? Your code don not protect any invariants if I know your class internal structure and apply reflection to add routes or do anything else.

Comment: We're talking about encapsulation. encapsulation wouldn't be needed if we could count on every one to use the code exactly as it was intended. But we can't. Sometimes that out of a misunderstanding, lack of skills of simply because of a bug. So we guard the code against usage that would break the invariants. Not by declaration but by implementation

Comment: `if (cicrularRouts is IList<CircularRoute>)`. `if (cicrularRouts is IDictionary<int,CircularRoute>)`.

Comment: This discussion is going way over my head! :) I'll give the IEnumerable<T> properties and methods a try and report back here. Thanks for the help, it's appreciated.

Comment: @Oded, RuneFs `Type type = typeof(Bus);
FieldInfo field = type.GetField("circularRoutes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var circularRoutes = (List<CircularRoute>)field.GetValue(bus);
circularRoutes.Add(new CircularRoute());` say good night to your invariants. I can do it *because I need to*

Comment: I used this solution and it worked perfectly for my project's needs. Thanks to everyone for their input!

Answer (score 2):

Do not expose the lists as public - keep them private and provide methods to add to each list.

In these methods, you can *check* for the counts of both lists and only add if they are under your threshold.

If you need to expose the lists, I suggest returning *copies* of these private lists (using a copy constructor), so the invariants are not violated.

```
private List<CircularRoute> circularRoute = new List<CircularRoute>();

public AddRoute(CircularRoute route)
{
  if(circularRoute.Count + longDistance.Count < threshold)
  {
    // add logic.
  }
  else
  {
    // Perhaps throw an exception
  }
}

public IEnumerable<CircularRoute> CircularRoutes
{
   get { return new List<CircularRoute>(circularRoute); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lists by themselves, no.  You could potentially do it if the underlying implementation was an ObservableCollection.

The other way you could do it is via polling.  However, that wouldn't prevent you getting into an invalid state.  It would only tell you once you got into it.

Lists by themselves won't support the requested functionality.